# Include with t4 templates

Tags: c#, templates, t4

I am trying to use Include to embed one template within another.  This should by way of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx) work but I am having an issue.  Seel example below.

**Example:**

*LicenceHeader.tt*

```
// stuff here
// 
<#@include file="AboutHeader.tt" #>
```

*AboutHeader.tt*

```
// different stuff
```

*Main.tt*

```
<#@include file="LicenceHeader.tt" #>
```

When i try to transform Main.tt it results in the following error.

> Loading the include file 'AboutHeader.tt' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run. "

If I change main.tt to the code below and transform it it works

**Main.tt**

```
<#@include file="LicenceHeader.tt" #> 
<#@include file="AboutHeader.tt" #>
```

My guess is that there is an issue with the generator finding the AboutHeader.tt when its embeded within another template.  I have the templates set to copy always.   Should I be supplying a directory some how?  I did try `$(myIncludeFolder)\` but it didnt work and using $(TargetDir) also didnt work.

Actuall file locations:

**Main template full path is this**

```
C:\\Users\\HP_User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\SampleBuilder\\Src\\GoogleSampleBuilder\\GoogleSampleBuilder\\Templates\\Csharp\\MethodTemplate.tt
```

I set the two sub templates to copy local since i wanted to avoid embeding full path into a template.   The path is actually stored as a property in app.config.

**Directory layout**

Project 
-> templates 
-----> Csharp
------------> MainTemplate.tt
------------> AboutHeader.tt
------------> LicenceHeader.tt

Template called using the full path above  `var host = new TemplateHost(templateFileName);`

Comment: If do this exactly as you describe here - everything works fine. Ensure that you use correct names in includes everywhere (for example, if you will include LicenseHeader.tt instead of LicenceHeader.tt, or misspell AboutHeader somehow - you will have such error).

Comment: I tried a copy paste thing to make sure its not a spelling issue. If i copy the line from main.tt and put it in LicenceHeader.tt it doesnt work its the exact same line :/

Comment: Maybe you can provide a layout of your templates (in which folder(s) they are located). Or maybe your templates are more complex that what you provided in question (I tried with exact content you provided).

Comment: there you go.  Wonder if i should just set the main template to just copy local as well.  However ideal i would like to have them reading for a specific directory since i will in the end be generating for different programming languages which will all have different templates.

Comment: So you don't have all 3 templates side by side in one Visual Studio project? When I tested I put them side by side (without copy local since that was not needed).

Comment: Technical speaking they are all in that directory. Maybe I shouldn't have set the sub ones to copy local :/

Comment: Well it's hard to help without reproduceable example. Can you show your complete csproj file (of a project which all those templates are part of).

Comment: kind of hard its a huge project all 3 templates are in the same directory.  Setting them not to copy local didnt help.